# Android AsyncTask : Passing single "String" from ArayList to be executed

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'mm trying to pass single "string" to `AsyncTask`. I was searching whole day, and still I can't get it. I have some data in `ArrayList` and I get one data (string) to `AsyncTask`, and it's not working. But when I pass string with quotes, its works. Here's my 1st example code from `ArrayList` :

```
ArrayList<String> example= new ArrayList<String>();//we consider it have data
new Mytask().execute(example.get(0).toString());
```

Here's my 2nd code with single quotes string :

```
String example="exm";
new Mytask().execute(example);
```

and this is my AsyncTask code :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String str = params[0];

    return str;
 }
```

I used AsyncTask code for both method : ArrayList and single string. But it only works from string with quotes, and I have been trying another method like this, but still not working:

```
ArrayList<String> example= new ArrayList<String>();
String exmpl=example.get(0).toString();
new Mytask().execute(exmpl);
```

Please help me, where is my mistake, And how can I solve this. thanks

**UPDATE** : Here's my complete code :

```
public class MasterTokoActivity extends Activity{

TextView new_namaToko,new_alamat;
Spinner new_provinsi,new_kota,new_kecamatan;
mydatabase db;
ProgressBar load_prov,load_kota,load_kec;

ArrayList<String> propinsi = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mastertoko);

    new_namaToko = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_namaToko);
    new_alamat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_alamat);
    new_provinsi = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.new_provinsi);
    new_kota = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.new_kota);
    load_prov = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.load_prov);
    load_kota = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.load_kota);

    new MyasyncTask().execute();
    new_provinsi.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id){

            new MyasyncTaskkota().execute(propinsi.get(pos));
    }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

public class MyasyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>{

    @Override
     public void onPreExecute() {       
        load_prov.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new_provinsi.setClickable(false);
        new_provinsi.setEnabled(false);
      }

     @Override
     protected Integer doInBackground(String... arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
         int result=-1;

            db = new mydatabase(getApplicationContext());
            propinsi=db.ambilProvinsi();             
     if(propinsi.size()!=0)
     { 
        result=1;
     }
     return result;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
         super.onPostExecute(result);   
         if(result==1){

             ArrayAdapter<String> adapterProv = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MasterTokoActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, propinsi);
             adapterProv.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             new_provinsi.setAdapter(adapterProv);

         }
         load_prov.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         new_provinsi.setClickable(true);
         new_provinsi.setEnabled(true);


     }
     }

public class MyasyncTaskkota extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>{
    ArrayList<String> kota = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
     public void onPreExecute() {       
        load_kota.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new_kota.setClickable(false);
        new_kota.setEnabled(false);
      }

     @Override
     protected Integer doInBackground(String... prov) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
         int result=-1;
            db = new mydatabase(getApplicationContext());
            kota=db.ambilKota(prov[0]);
     if(kota.size()!=0)
     { 
        result=1;
     }
     return result;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
         super.onPostExecute(result);   
         if(result==1){

             ArrayAdapter<String> adapterKota = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MasterTokoActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, kota);
             adapterKota.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
             new_kota.setAdapter(adapterKota);
             adapterKota.notifyDataSetChanged();
         }
         load_kota.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         new_kota.setClickable(true);
        new_kota.setEnabled(true);
     }
     }
}
```

This is `ambilProvinsi()` method in my database helper :

```
public ArrayList<String> ambilProvinsi(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur;

    ArrayList<String> sv=new ArrayList<String>();

    cur = db.query("propinsi", new String []{"nama_propinsi"}, null, null, null, null, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    if (!cur.isAfterLast()){
        do{                 
            sv.add(cur.getString(0));
        }while (cur.moveToNext());
    }

return sv;
}
```

and there is no error in logCat.

Comment: Using example.get(0).toString() is unnecessary, just use example.get(0).  It's an already an ArrayList<String>(), so using toString() is redundant.

Comment: What does this mean, "//we consider it have data"? Does it have data or not before you call `get(0)` on it?

Comment: i already use `example.get(0)` too. but it's also not working

Comment: @codeMagic it have data, and then i call `get(0)`

Comment: Have you tried to clear your project? Sometimes that kind of error occurs and clear the project may solve. It's annoying, I know, but clearing the project saved me a lot of time and also avoided a big headache

Comment: And when you say "it's not working", what you mean? What does logcat says?

Comment: propinsi is filled from a thread, and then its data is being used in another thread, may be try filling propinsi in the main thread before u execute the MyasyncTaskkota task, or let MyasyncTask task finish before starting MyasyncTaskkota

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answering guys, all my code works now, nothing need to change.
the problem come from my data encode. once i change my data encode to utf8, my app running normally.`Charset` for Android can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, using toString() is redundant, so you should take that out.  Also, are you sure you aren't passing null/empty data?  You're definitely not checking your inputs...First of all, you should change:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String str = params[0];

    if(str == null)     
         throw new NullPointerException("Provided null string to: " + getClass().getSimpleName());

    return str;
 }
```

Comment: i alreday check it before i pass it to asynctask. i print it using toast just before i call `new Mytask().execute(example.get(0).toString());` . and it show me not null

Comment: Post more of your original source, because from the code above - it's obvious that you are calling get on an empty ArrayList.  If that's not what you're doing in your actual code, how are we suppose to help find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. But you can try to pass your string in constructor, i think it must work.

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private final String str;

    public MyTask(final String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //process this.str and return result
    }

    //post execute 
}
```

and call

```
new MyTask(someString).execute();
```

Also you have forgotten to close cursor in `ambilProvinsi()` method.